# IMC Module in kamailio

Tags: module, sip, kamailio

As I am trying to install new **imc module** to my kamailio sip server, I also followed the documentation of it. But unfortunately, I could not run kamailio sip server.

The error which is coming while running it is on this line:

```
modparam("imc","db_mysql","DBURL")
```

Where

```
DBURL = "mysql://kamailio:kamailiorw@localhost/kamailio"
```

The errors are like `syntax error` and `invalid arguments`

What could be the possible chances of this kind of error?
In last what can be the best imc testing software or client?
Please help.

Comment: Pleases elaborate . . .

Answer (score 0):

You've set `db_mysql` instead of `db_url` while defining a module parameters. please change it to.

```
modparam("imc","db_url", DBURL)
```

Also make sure you're loading this module after `db_mysql` and `tm` module.
http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/3.2.x/modules_k/imc.html#idp1754096

And as it follows the architecture of IRC channels you can use many IRC chat clients to connect such as Pidgin, mIRC and Icechat for Windows, Limechat for Mac OS X, Irssi, WeeChat or XChat for Unix-like systems, ChatZilla for Mozilla browsers or any other standard IRC program.